# Show an image in moodle form

Tags: php, moodle

I am using Moodle 3.1+. I have created a plugin to add and edit contents in a database table. Now I want to show an image uploaded by the user inside moodle form. I can add an HTML tag element in form to show an image. But the problem is that the path of the image is taken from the database table.  How can I achieve this? Please help.

Comment: Do you know how to upload images using php? Because thats where you would want to start i assume.

Comment: @KenziieeFlavius I know how to upload images in php. The problem is related to moodle. In moodle the form is created using a class and then we create the object to display the form. So I can't give the path where the form is defined.

Comment: It would be great to give some example code, i didnt know you meant moodle specifically

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the *static* element.

```
$mform->addElement('static', 'elementName', 'elementLabel', $htmlcode);
```

Where `$htmlCode` contains your image tag.

To pass additional data to your form, you must use the `customdata` argument of the constructor, here is an example:

```
$form = new your_form(null, array('userid' => 2, 'foo' => 'bar'));
```

Then, inside your form, those are accessible like this:

```
$this->_customdata['userid']; // Contains 2.
$this->_customdata['foo']; // Contains 'bar'.
```

Comment: How can I change the value of that? How to pass a value to that element?

Comment: Form is defined in a class, and then the object is instantiated to display the course. How can I assign a value after the object is instantiated?

Comment: I have edited my answer, does that answer your question?

Comment: I want to assign the values after form submission also

Comment: Then, use the method `definition_after_data` to add or alter your element.